# What is the function to set Alerts (not Alert() function) in MQL4 (metatrader)?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, alerts

**Confusing terms clarification:**

- Type 1: Alert() function in mql4
- Type 2: Alerts that can be set on the UI of metatrader -see the image

My question is related to **type 2** Alerts.

[image]

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to set alert via MQL4? Just looking for the right function name.

My searches simply returned references to the type 1 alerts, nothing on type 2.

**NOTE:**
I am not looking for an indiactor solution.

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are no inbuilt functions that enable you to set alerts in the Terminal Tab. The alerts that are set are stored in the following folder:

`<MT4 Data Folder>/profiles/alerts.ini`

You could possibly figure out the format of the stored information in the `alerts.ini` file, but you would need to read/write to it using Windows OS functions. You can read about this on the following page:

[File Operations via WinAPI](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/1540)

Answer (score -1):

```
    if(TimeCurrent() > LastTimeSaved+Delay && AlertCount <= maxiterations)
    {
     AlertCount++;
     LastTimeSaved=TimeCurrent();
     PlaySound("alert.wav"); Alert("Max Trades Reached!!!");     
    }
```

for example

Comment: Your answer does not address the question.

Comment: I've been writing code in mql4 professionally since 2008. Since the solution to what you wrote is not directly, unfortunately, I gave the closest answer. My mistake, I shouldn't have answered your question.